# Sending command to worldserver without attaching to it

Tags: docker, docker-compose, tty, azerothcore

I'm running [AzerothCore from the docker container](http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Install-with-Docker#setup). It's running pretty smooth and without problems.

I'm trying to create users on the `worldserver` container without attaching to it or using the database directly.

I've tried:

```
echo "account create account password" | docker attach <your container>
```

got back: `the input device is not a TTY`

I have also tried running `docker-compose exec` but also without any success.

What am I missing?

Do I recall correctly, that there was a CLI somewhere with a separate CLI port?

Comment: have you tried this: '-T Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose exec` allocates a TTY.'

Comment: I've tried:
echo "account create acc pass" | docker exec --tty ac-worldserver_1

result: "docker exec" requires at least 2 arguments. (obvioysly)
From the man docker exec I've found:
-t, --tty[=false] Allocate a pseudo-TTY
But, as you can see it didn't work.

If I pass the account create as a command:

docker exec --tty ac-worldserver_1 "account create acc pass"
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"account create acc pass\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

exactly same erro same with docker-compose

Comment: might have a look at the command `mkfifo`

Answer (score 1):

docker exec will try to run the program you pass in an argument.

The proper way would be to add Telnet remote access: https://github.com/azerothcore/wiki/blob/master/docs/Remote-Access.md

```
Ra.Enable = 1 in worldserver.conf

Get docker container IP : docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ac-worldserver_1
```

Connect to it : telnet   (default port is 3443)

then enter your worldserver commands (account create ...)